# Cannot use abigen to make vyper bindings

Tags: vyper

using the command

```
abigen --vy=uniswap_exchange.vy --pkg=uniswap --out=UniswapExchange.go
```

results in the error: `flag provided but not defined: -vy`

support for the vyper compiler was just added a few days ago so I wanted to give it a try. I have the vyper compiler install in a virtual env which is running when trying the command above. I have also tested the compiler and it is working on my machine, and made sure to replace the abigen binaries using the

```
make && make devtools
```

command after updating my local go-ethereum source code.

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should probably be aware of https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/08/update-on-the-vyper-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

Download the last https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum , and

```
make all
```

to build the tools.

To install to your go-path

```
go install github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/abigen
```

or download them directly [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/)

after you have the last abigen on your path, use, for example:

```
abigen --vy ./contracts/mutual.vy --pkg contracts --out ./contracts/mutual.go
```

to transpile it